# add files opened in Emacs to GNOME's recently used document list

Tags: gnome, emacs, elisp

I there any way to automatically add files opened in Emacs to Gnome's recently used document list?

[This one](http://zerotau.blogspot.com/2006/05/recent-documents-emacs-and-gnome.html) doesn't work as Gnome uses another file format now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I did it myself: http://www.florian-diesch.de/doc/emacs/add-to-gnomes-recently-used-documents/